# How can I derive the covariant derivative of the Ricci tensor using the Ricci scalar?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, curvature

\begin{align*} R&=g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu}\\ \Rightarrow \nabla^{\gamma} R&=\nabla^{\gamma}(g^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu})\\ &=\nabla^{\gamma}(g^{\mu\nu})R_{\mu\nu}+g^{\mu\nu}\nabla ^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu})\\ &=g^{\mu\nu}\nabla ^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu})\\& g_{\alpha\beta}\nabla ^{\gamma}R= g_{\alpha\beta}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu})\\&g_{\alpha\beta}\nabla ^{\gamma}R=g_{\alpha\beta}g^{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}}\nabla ^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu})\\&g_{\alpha\beta}\nabla ^{\gamma}R=4\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}}\nabla ^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu})\\&g _{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}}\nabla ^{\gamma}R=4\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}}\nabla ^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu})\\&g _{\mu\nu}\nabla ^{\gamma}R=4\nabla ^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu})\\&\nabla^{\gamma}(R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{4}g_{\mu\nu}R)=0\end{align*}

I was trying to derive the covariant derivative of the Ricci tensor using the Ricci scalar instead of using the Bianchi Identities and I am stuck. What am I missing?

Comment: 6th line is fishy. You already have $\alpha \beta$ in $g_{\alpha \beta}$ but you added contractions $g^{\alpha \beta}\dfrac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^\alpha}\dfrac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\beta}$. I haven't gone through the calculation, but try using different indices for this contraction.

Comment: Oh, I have just seen my mistake. Thanks.